# Axios correct type for $post, $get

Tags: typescript, axios, typescript-typings

When I import Axios and try using $get or $post, I'm getting an error in IDE:

`Property '$get' does not exist on type 'AxiosStatic'. Did you mean 'get'?`

```
import axios from 'axios';

user = axios.$get('/api/auth/me/');
```

How to use correct typings in this case?

Comment: npm i @types/axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at typings in attached image only the below methods can be used 
[image]